# OCR for Sanskrit ( OR devanagari)

Tags: unicode, ocr

I need an OCR s/w for Sanskrit OR devanagari.

I need a s/w which can convers character into UNICODE.

Answer (score 0):

use sanskritocr, then paste the output [here](http://technical-hindi.googlegroups.com/web/SanskritOCR-Roman-text-to-Unicode+converter05.htm) 
to convert the character to unicode.